# CSS color behaving differently in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg, components

I have a component that contains a `<svg>` element with a color attribute of blue. In Chrome I have the expected behaviours, where as in IE the color doesn't apply. When I inspect the element.

[image]

We can see that the color is in fact blue but it is not displaying blue. Any idea of this sort of behaviour in IE?

[image]

EDIT:

here's the css for color attribute.

```
.blue {
  & path {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Path's don't have colors, they have strokes & fills in an SVG. Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

To make PaulieD's answer more explicit, you need to use `fill` not `color`.

```
.blue {
  & path {
    fill: blue;
  }
}
```